# release and unload methods of the SoundPool

Tags: android, soundpool

Do I have to use *release* or *unload* methods of the SoundPool object after using it. I mean, is there any memory leakage problem when I close my application If I don't use *release* or *unload* methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must!

I always create a separate Sound class (sort of utils), which has all the play, load, unload etc methods. I access these from all of my activities in a static fashion i.e. Unload sound from onStop() or onPause() and load sound in onResume(). Make sure that you use the application context to load sounds lest you will end up leaking memory (if you use activity context)